# Blocking an App update after mod

Tags: android

I have decompiled one app from playstore, edited some files & images as per my requirement. Then I have recompiled and installed on my device. 
Now I want to know is there a option we can stop the app update in play store when there is a new version of the original app is available on play store.

Let me know if there is a chance to do this from coding level.

Answer (score 1):

Since you recompiled it, you must have resigned it.  So the security keys won't match (unless you happened to have their release key and used it).  So it won't update ever.

Comment: Yes,after recompiling I have signed it. So when its updating.. It will be like first checking the keys, if it match with official app version then only will it be updated??

Comment: Yes.  Its part of the security model.  To see an example-  compile the app with a new key, then try to install it.  You'll get a keymismatch error.